# Como aplicar transparência gradativamente em um LinearLayout

Tags: android

Bom dia!

Estou com dificuldade em encontrar alguma propriedade do LinearLayout para controlar a transparência.

Minha situação é a seguinte tenho um LinearLayout com uma imagem de fundo, e também tenho HomeScrollViewObserver para todo o XML no método onScrollChanged da HomeScrollViewObserver preciso aplicar um efeito de transparência ou suavizar a troca da imagem de fundo.

Segue abaixo um trecho do código, este código somente esta trocando a imagem de fundo.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_icons_path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home_icons_path"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//Método que controla a rolagem da tela na vertical(y) e horizontal(x)
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(HomeScrollViewObserver scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    //Coloca a imagem de fundo padrão (fundo branco) somente é alterado quando o valor y for menor ou igual a 5
    if (y <= 100) {
        ll_icons_path.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_icons_path);
    } else {
        //Verifica se o valor de y é maior ou igual a 6 e muda imagem de fundo(fundo transparente)
        if (y >= 101){
            ll_icons_path.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_icons_path_semfundo);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se calhar não entendi a sua pergunta mas pode controlar a transparência de uma *ImageView* através de `setAlpha()`(setImageAlpha() API16+).

Comment: Quando o `y` for igual a 100 quer que as imagens tenham 50% de transparência cada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes aplicar um background ao linear layout com gradient:

gradient_background.xml

```
<shape>
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Este é um gradient que começa na cor preto e vai até preto 100% transparent, obtendo o que pretendes.

Depois basta aplicares este fundo ao background do linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_icons_path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Edição:

background_multiplo.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_image" />
    <item>
         <shape>
             <gradient
                 android:angle="270"
                 android:startColor="#000"
                 android:endColor="#00000000"
                 android:type="linear" />
         </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Com este background podes adicionar um drawable como fundo e depois o gradiente. O teu linear layout vai ser algo como:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_icons_path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_multiplo"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Se o que pretendes é que a própria imagem vá desaparecendo, então tens de alterar a própria imagem!

Comment: Bom dia! 

Rui Santos,

Obrigado pelo retorno, infelizmente não vai rolar, pois da maneira que você esta sugerindo é preciso trocar a imagem de fundo. No modelo que eu mandei eu já estou usando uma imagem de fundo no LinearLayout.

Att.

Comment: Então podes usar um drawable com várias camadas, uma para o fundo outra para o gradiente! Vou atualizar.

Comment: Olá Rui Santos, para transparência funcionou muito bem obrigado, mas para parte de trocar a imagem de fundo de uma forma suave como eu faria?

Comment: Experimenta esta library: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations para usar uma animação de fadeIn/fadeOut quando o y é maior ou menos 100 como no eu exemplo.